# Azure data factory -ingesting the data from csv file to sql table- data activity sql sink stored procedure -table type and table type parameter name

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am running one of the existing Azure data factory pipeline that contains instet into sql table, where the sink is a sql server stored procedure.
I supplied the table type and table type parameter name and which maps to my table.
I am getting error as Failure happened on 'Sink' side.

[image]

```
Storedprocedure:
CREATE PROCEDURE [ods].[Insert_EJ_Bing]
    @InputTable [ods].[EJ_Bing_Type] READONLY,
    @FileName varchar(1000)
AS
BEGIN
insert into #workingtable 
    (
    [ROWHASH],
    [Date])
select [ROWHASH],
    [Date] from     @InputTable
end
```

Error message:
Failure happened on 'Sink' side.
ErrorCode=InvalidParameter,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The value of the property '' is invalid:
'Invalid 3 part name format for TypeName.'.,Source=,''Type=System.ArgumentException,Message=Invalid 3 part name format for TypeName.,Source=System.Data

Can anyone please let me where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your approach or code. You are getting this error because of the way you specified the `Table type` value in the sink.


[image]

I got **same error** as you with the above table type.

[image]

Change the Table type from `[dbo.][tabletype]` to `[dbo].[tabletype]`

[image]

You can see my **copy activity is successful**.

**Rather than typing the stored procedure name and Table type names, you can do like below.**

[image]